# How to modify the IP for a docker container?

Tags: docker, sles

I'm new to docker. And currently faced one problem --
I've downloaded a sles11sp4 image from dockerhub -- https://hub.docker.com/r/darksheer/sles11sp4
And when I run it -- docker run -i -t darksheer/sles11sp4 /bin/bash  -- I found there's a IP and MAC already set on it --

```
docker:~ # docker run -i -t darksheer/sles11sp4 /bin/bash
145636fbb570:/ # ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:AC:11:00:02
          inet addr:172.17.0.2  Bcast:172.17.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:696 (696.0 b)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 b)
```

Since this IP is not same LAN with the host( 192.168.95.66 ), I want to modify it to another IP( 192.168.95.75)  to make this container visible on the network. So I tried to run it with "--ip xxxx" parameters , but failed --

```
docker:~ # docker run -i -t --ip 192.168.95.67 darksheer/sles11sp4 /bin/bash
29fda722cf70:/ # ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:AC:11:00:02
          inet addr:172.17.0.2  Bcast:172.17.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:696 (696.0 b)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 b)
```

Then I found there's no network card script on this image, so I can't modify it inside container --

```
29fda722cf70:/ # cd /etc/sysconfig/network/
29fda722cf70:/etc/sysconfig/network # ls
if-down.d  if-up.d  providers  scripts
29fda722cf70:/etc/sysconfig/network # cd if-up.d/
29fda722cf70:/etc/sysconfig/network/if-up.d # ls
29fda722cf70:/etc/sysconfig/network/if-up.d # cd ..
29fda722cf70:/etc/sysconfig/network # cd scripts/
29fda722cf70:/etc/sysconfig/network/scripts # ls
29fda722cf70:/etc/sysconfig/network/scripts # cd ..
29fda722cf70:/etc/sysconfig/network # cd providers/
29fda722cf70:/etc/sysconfig/network/providers # ls
29fda722cf70://etc/sysconfig/network/providers # cd ../scripts/
29fda722cf70:/etc/sysconfig/network/scripts # ls
29fda722cf70:/etc/sysconfig/network/scripts #
29fda722cf70:/etc # cd /etc/udev/rules.d/
29fda722cf70:/etc/udev/rules.d # ls

 Then I confused -- how to set a new IP to a container like this? Please kind help. Thanks
```

Regards
Eisen

Comment: You can usually almost completely ignore the Docker-internal IP addresses: they will be different from your host IP but you never need to know them, set them, or directly connect to them.  Docker manages the entire networking setup for you.  Use the [`docker run -p`](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/#published-ports) option to make a container port accessible from outside.

Comment: Thanks David. Your comment is helpful. But here-- something might be different -- as I want to install a sybase IQ server on it. So to generate a license for it I need this container to have a valid IP and a valid MAC... That's why I have to modify it... :)

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer --

1. docker network create --subnet=192.168.97.0/24 net1
2. docker run --net net1 --ip 192.168.97.67 -i -t darksheer/sles11sp4 /bin/bash

   6ced18aaeeb6:/ # ifconfig
   eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:C0:A8:61:43
   inet addr:192.168.97.67  Bcast:192.168.97.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
   UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1